# What is the right query to get the required records in this set of tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the following diagram:
[image: Diagram of tables with primary keys, foreign keys and relations]

What is the right query to:
get the rows in client_billings with client_d = 111 (for example) that don't have any row in billing_codes with the same item_code_id.

The relations between the tables (in case it is not clear from the diagram) are:

```
client_billings.client_id             n:1  clients.id
clients.id                            1:n  billing_code_clients.client_id
billing_code_clients.billing_code_id  n:1  billing_codes.id
item_codes.id                         1:n  billing_codes.item_code_id
item_codes.id                         1:n  client_billings.item_code_id
```

For clarification purposes, I am showing next the query that will get the rows in client_billings that **do** have at least one row in billing_codes with the same item_code_id (the query may be wrong though):

```
SELECT cb.*
  FROM client_billings cb
  JOIN clients c ON c.id = cb.client_id
  JOIN item_codes ic ON ic.id = cb.item_code_id
  JOIN billing_code_clients bcc ON bcc.client_id = c.id
  JOIN billing_codes bc ON bc.id = bcc.billing_code_id AND bc.item_code_id = cb.item_code_id
 WHERE cb.client_id = 'XXX'
```

Comment: *get the rows in client_billings with client_d = 111 (for example) that don't have any row in billing_codes with the same item_code_id.* WHERE NOT EXISTS.

Comment: Thanks @Akina. Would you mind to elaborate your answer a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's this.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM client_billings cb
JOIN clients c ON cb.client_id = c.id
JOIN billing_code_clients bcc ON bcc.client_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN billing_codes bc ON bc.id = bcc.billing_code_id
WHERE cb.client_id = 111
AND bc.item_code_id <> cb.item_code_id
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan Clark, but it doesn't work. I run "SELECT * FROM client_billings WHERE item_code_id = 2511 AND client_id = 18" and it returned one row. Then, I run "SELECT *
  FROM billing_codes bc
  JOIN billing_code_clients bcc ON bcc.billing_code_id = bc.id
 WHERE bc.item_code_id = 2511
   AND bcc.client_id = 18" and it didn't return any rows. Then, I run your query with the correct client_id and it didn't return any rows. Your query should have returned at least one row with the client_id and item_code_id I indicated.

Comment: Have you got some test data perhaps?